# SQUID: detect Website name entered by user in browser

Tags: proxy, squid

I am using squid as an explicit proxy within my organization to block certain websites in my infrastructure. I have successfully set it up using url_rewrite_program and ssl_bump features and its working like a charm.

The problem is, so far, i am not successful in figuring out the main website url either in squid's access.log  or url_rewrite_program. i.e. when user accesses a website say http://www.yahoo.com, a large number of requests to many different hosts are logged and i cannot figure out which website user actually wanted to access. I also tried looking at referer header field and found out most of the time its not set. specially for https connect request.

Is there a neat and clean way to find out which websites are actually visited by users and which urls are actually requested internally by the webpage. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear and neat way to detect which site the user was visiting is to look at the `Host` header of the HTTP request. If the user enters the address into the address bar and the user's browser opens a dozen of various URLs, it means that user is visiting all of these sites. The difference between "a user is visiting a site" and "a browser is visiting a site" is strictly philosophical: a browser visits a site on behalf of a user's request.

The only reason when you actually cannot be sure what site does user visit is the case when user visits the site with an HTTPS request, which squid will log as a `CONNECT` request with an IP address of the peer. But since you implemented successfully sslBump, there should be no complications: for bumped and stared sites squid will know exactly what they are. The others will depend on a number of factors.